# What exactly is tested when a fire extinguisher is tagged?

Tags: fire

I am just curious: the obvious is that the

- pressure
- mass
- [hydrostatic test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrostatic_test)

can be inspected /measured to ensure that the device has not been discharged. Is there anything else that is measured \ checked?

Answer (score 5):

Hydrostatic test is typically only on a 5 year cycle, and involves emptying/recharging due to the nature of that test.

Otherwise it's pretty much pressure gauge or weight, and overall visual inspection - hoses (if any) not deteriorated, pins intact and in place, and insurance company has documentation that they were present and appeared to be functional from an independent source

Comment: On the tanks I have tested on the 5 year cycle they are tested at 5/3 working pressure and measured for expansion if they expand two much they are no longer refillable, there is a 10 year hydro this is for tanks used in place and there is a star after the test date.